# Git submodule causing error with npm

Tags: git, npm

I have a git repo. Within that git repo is a library I'm making (not registered as a submodule). That has it's own git repo.

```
.
├── _node_modules
|   ├── _my_library
|       ├── .git
|       └── _package.json
├── .git
└── package.json
```

This is causing an issue with node npm. When I try to install a package, I get this error:

```
parent_repo/node_modules/my_library: Appears to be a git repo or submodule.
```

I can install npm packages in the submodule, but not the parent one. How can I fix this?

Comment: Either move  the library outside your main project or create a submodule.

Comment: Well I need it within the project. I've tried creating a submodule, but I get some confusing error messages. I'll update the question with the error messages.

Comment: If it be dependent on the outer project then maybe it should be part of the project.  If not, then move it out and include it during the build process.

Comment: Would that mean I have to publish it to npm first?